# Handling Json data with tab fragments in android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I am new to android development. I am trying to access json data in android. I have two tabs with viewpager . First tab contains information about events and the second tab will have a custom listview having a list of students attending that event.

this is the link to my json -https://jsonblob.com/5695f83de4b01190df49255d

I am confused on how to access this data in each fragment. My first screen has a edittext where the user will enter the event id.

Here is the link of design
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5XX8x3YUUrqYWUxNGdyckVaQ00/view?usp=sharing

I have developed the interface . Can anyone please help me with implementing the functionality.

thank you.

Comment: I want to say that the url you given is wrong. The true url is [http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/5695f83de4b01190df49255d](http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/5695f83de4b01190df49255d) if you want send a normal Get request. And you can use APIKitchen to check it.

Comment: [see here for volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)//
[see here for retrofit](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lalit Pratap Singh's answer is correct.
And i post my way below:

That's the answer.
http://7xphy5.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/A28B70BF-31C1-48F4-9BF9-61DB197A864B.png

1.Correct your url according my comment. http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/5695f83de4b01190df49255d

2.Get the response use APIKitchen or search the url on the internet and then you will get the response like this. Copy all the content.
http://7xphy5.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/A015706D-59E9-4E6C-B855-30B1152D30B6.png

3.Use a plugin in `Android Studio` called `GsonFormat`. Paste the content to plugin and it will create a new `Events.java` for you.

4.Use Retrofit to get the RESTFul Data.

I didn't paste my code here. You can leave your e-mail and i'll send code and detail explanatioin to you.

Comment: Thank you for replying . I have created a class using Gson format and i want to access the id . I am using Retrofit .  email - kaustubhbhagwat93@gmail.com . Any help will be great,

Comment: I already send you an e-mail, you can reply through email directly if you still have questions.

Comment: I did not get your email bro please send it again -  kaustubhbhagwat93@gmail.com

Comment: Sry bro, i didn't noticed email send failed. And i've send again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Application class in your code.

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {
       public static MyApplication mInstance;
       public String jsonStr;


       @Override
       public void onCreate(){
           super.onCreate();
           mInstance = this;
       }

       public MyApplication getmInstance(){
           return mInstance;
       }

       public void setJsonStr(String jsonStr){
           this.jsonStr = jsonStr;
       }

       public String getJsonStr(){
           return jsonStr;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Add application class in you manifest file

   ```
   android:name=".MyApplication"
   ```
3. Fetch json data and set it to application class like from anywhere in you application

   ```
   MyApplication.getmInstance().setJsonStr(jsonstr);//fetched json data from httpcall
   ```
4. Get all data from Runtime and do any operation on it

   ```
   String jsonStr = MyApplication.getmInstance().getJsonStr();
   ```